# Rotation and Scale have suddenly stopped working?

Tags: interface, 3d-view, workflow, transforms

I was working quickly, (making mistakes), and suddenly rotation and scale transforms stopped working. I think I hit some shortcut or button by accident. Translate still works though. I checked that the transforms weren't locked and such, to no avail. What could be the cause?

Answer (score 21, accepted):

The cause is the manipulate object centers only button (<kbd>Alt</kbd><kbd>,</kbd>):

[image]

When it is selected, scale and rotate no longer function normally.

Instead, of or rotating the mesh with the object origin, only the origin moves:

[image]